# Inductor circuit model

Tags: inductor

I'm looking for a equivalent model of an inductor with Rac due to skin effect. What is the equivalent schematic? I found two of them, is it the first one or the second one which is correct?
Does is exist a method to find the value of the Rac?

Thanks for your help

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9DP1S.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I would say neither is appropriate without a list of warnings so, where did you find these versions (you said "I found two of them")?

Comment: by typing on the net coil equivalent circuit I found : https://hyperelectronic.net/wiki/inductor/inductor-impedance/ https://www.ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/L_Inductor.htm

Answer (score 0):

Neither is any more or less correct than the other. Both models are equivalent, in fact, for slightly adjusted values of the components.

There are infinitely many models one can use, all with their benefits and drawbacks. Without knowing exactly what nonidealities you do and don't need to model, we can't tell you what would be the best model to use.

Comment: So if both models could be correct, what is the way to find parasitics elements Rac and Cpar ?

Comment: Hook up your inductor to a network analyzer.

Comment: Does the network analyzer could indicates Rac and Cpar ?

Comment: @exolune Not directly, but it will give you readings from which you can calculate them.